# For Mysql, how can "boxing" of output be suppressed when using -e?

Tags: mysql

I want to make a quick query that'll return one record from a mysql DB from the linux command line.  I am planning on using "mysql -e".  Works fine except that it returns hyphens, vert bars and plus signs to "box" the output.  Example...

```
% mysql -h whatever -u whatever -p<whatever> mydb -N -e "select finish from 
the_table where status like 'PASS%' order by start desc limit 1"
+---------------------+
| 2018-02-13 19:57:30 |
+---------------------+
```

Is there a way to suppress all the hyphens, very bars and "+" signs and just get...

```
2018-02-13 19:57:30
```

I found -N suppressing the header (that was good) but didn't see anything obvious to suppress the "boxing".

I suppose I could awk and sed it into submission, but I was looking for something simpler.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Give `-s` a try.

Comment: `man mysql` is a good place to hunt for info like this too.